# How to wrap the divs in CSS using FLEX

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having the below Code which places 3 elements in the same line- a div, a text box and another div : https://jsfiddle.net/Luz1myc3/1/ . CSS I am trying to use -

```
div.parent{
    display:flex;

}
```

My Question - I am trying to place the third div (which has a long text of second line) to wrap to the text box and then the rest of the long text should come in the next line just below the first div (First Line). The format expected is following-

[image: Expected]

I will be happy if this can be solved using flex. Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with flex.

Comment: what is the other option?

Answer (score 2):

Doing this using CSS Flex would seem very impractical, Flex isn't made to reproduce these kind of layouts. What you want to achieve requires a text to flow in an area that it isn't going to fill if you use Flex, unless you position it `absolute` but that's another challenge to position it perfectly.

The best option to achieve this layout is to use the good old `display: inline;` property.

```
div.parent{
    display: block;
}

div.parent > div {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Luz1myc3/2/

The text doesn't seem to be wrapping like you would want it to, so another way to do it is to use `float`.

```
div.parent{
    display: block;
}

div.parent > div {
  float: left;
}

div.parent > div.child {
  float: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Luz1myc3/4/

Comment: thanks deepak for the workaround but that really is not helping. I am still looking for another solution

Comment: What isn't helping exactly? The other one reproduces 90% of what you want to achieve. I wouldn't say I've given a 100% perfect solution, but this will at least get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

this is only a posibility but not a final solution..

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
} 

.child{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```